# Nvidia X Server issue

Tags: nvidia

I'm new to Ubuntu/ Linux, and I'm trying to install nvidia drivers. I've tried to install them from Ubuntu Software, but the app is empty. I've read some threads that had the same problem, but I can't figure it out what to do...
I turned off Secure Boot, and tried to install from nvidia website (https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us), bun when i run the .run file, it gives me an error which says that I have nvidia x server running... but i uninstalled it before trying to install it from .run file. What can I do, or what version should I install (from here: https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/unix/)? Thanks.

Im using nvidia gtx 1650 and ubuntu 21.10.

**Solved**
Downloaded again the driver from https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us

Opened the terminal on drive file location

Run the file - ./driver-name.run

And that was it.. :)

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? What is the Nvidia model?

Comment: Im using nvidia gtx 1650 and ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: You can install driver from "Software &  Updates", Drivers tab. Not "Ubuntu Software".

Comment: Solved from nvidia website, thanks.

Comment: It is a wrong way of installing drivers for Ubuntu. You'll find out it soon ;-)